# Sql performance more columns or more tables for reporting

Tags: sql-server, performance, multiple-columns

I have a sql database that was passed down to me that started of as an access application. Since then its evolved a lot. The previous developer stored additional columns on a table instead of splitting the tables and we are starting to report on this data (over 1m rows) and performance is starting to drag on some queries.

One table is for company and contains name, reference, address details, financial details, insurance etc.

I am thinking that we should split the table up and have `tblcompany`, `tbladdress`, `tblfinance` etc.  Since our reporting allows users to report on whatever fields they want. I think it would be better to inner join `tbladdress` if the user wants to report on address details, the same for finance, insurance etc. Also some companies may not have any finance details so whats the point in having lots of null fields?

Also its not just this table but other tables join to this table and the others are in the same format too. Just gave this one table as an example

So my question is would it improve performance? I think design wise it is the thing to do but wanted everyone's tips, tricks and opinions.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Note that questions asking for "tips, tricks and opinions" are likely to get closed: this site is for specific programming questions that are likely to have definitive answers. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to improve the performance of. Certainly normalisation is likely to improve it for collecting and maintaining data. But denormalisation tends to improve reporting. So the trick is to have two databases, one for each requirement, and populate reporting by mining the operational database. All depends on the load on the db and where you want to take the hit if you don't want to take the cost of setting up a reporting db.

All you can say is, reporting will slow down operational transactions and vice versa.

If you want the best performance you can get for both requirements, then two databases is the way to go, or you compromise...

Comment: I would like to improve the performance of reporting. Alot of queries that we are doing now seem to take a while to execute. Performance of saving the data is of less importance than reporting on the data. We actually have 200+ copies of this database setup (1 for each customer) so not sure if a separate reporting db for each would be an option

Comment: No point guessing at this, which is all I can do from here. Find the most popular slowest report query. Run it in a fully populated test DB a few times to get a performance figure. If it's slow with no other load, do an explain and look at optimising it. If it's fast, then you have a contention issue and you need to look at what locks are being used and can you safely twiddle with them.  Rinse and repeat. No one can give you a specific answer on this.

Comment: @user2736022, have a read at Kimball's [The Data Warehouse Toolkit: The Definitive Guide to Dimensional Modeling](http://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/books/data-warehouse-dw-toolkit/). The first few chapters might give you a very good idea what you need here even if you can't/won't implement a dimensional data model. As Tony hinted, one-by-one query optimization might not be effective enough.